# Python 2.7: Saving a plot from pandas

Tags: python, csv, plot, pandas, save

Using pandas I can in three simple lines create a plot from the data:

```
2014-07-06T10:00:00,12.6,12.9
2014-07-06T10:10:00,12.5,13.1
2014-07-06T10:20:00,12.5,13.1

import pandas as pd
plotdata = pd.read_csv('power_log.csv',header=None,names=['DateTime','ATS1','ATS2'],parse_dates = True, index_col = [0])
plotdata.plot()
```

However, I can't save this to a file with a plotdata.savefig().  The Savefig() function is a matplotlib function apparently not linked into pandas.

What are the options:

Is there something I've missed about redirecting a plot to a file in pandas?

Is there a 'typecast' to make the savefig work (I don't think that's the right language within Python)

Is it simply easier to use another module other than pandas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The simple one liner:

`df.plot().get_figure().savefig('figure.png')`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = plotdata.plot()
a.figure.savefig("output.png")
```

---

**EDIT: (2017)**

full example - still working (without `TypeError: 'Figure' object is not callable`)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([1,3,2])
a = df.plot()
a.figure.savefig("output.png")
```

Comment: This is wrong: `TypeError: 'Figure' object is not callable`

Comment: @mikal94305 what is wrong ? You shows some error without your code and you expect answer ? Create new post on Stackoverflow if you have problem with your code. BTW: this question has 3 years and module could changed. EDIT: I checked code and it still works for me.

Comment: @mikal94305 maybe you made mistake and you used `figure("output.png")` - it should give you error `TypeError: 'Figure' object is not callable`